# how to return when for/in function finishes in node js recursive function

Tags: node.js, json, recursion

I am iterating a nested json in node.js like below and want to fetch all the `attrList` where type is abc and create another json.

I am able to extract the required data and create output json.

But how should I return the final output array? I'm not able to figure out exiting/return condition. I am a newbie to node js, still learning. Can anyone help here?

```
 function recursion(input, output) {
    if (input["Type"] == "abc") {
        let attrlist = {};
          for (let i = 0; i < input["atrrlist"].length; i++) {

            attrlist[input["atrrlist"][i]["name"]] = input["atrrlist"][i]["val"];
        }
        if (input["atrrlist"].length > 0) {
            output[input["a"]] = attrlist;
        }
      }
    for (let obj in input) {
        if (typeof input[obj] == "object" && input[obj] !== null) {
             recursion(input[obj], output);
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling it like.

```
let output={};
recursion(input, output)
```

Input json is like below:

```
 {
  "a": "val",
 "b": "val2",
 "Type": "abc",
  atrrlist": [{
    "name": "vbv",
    "val": "vbv"
}],
"child": [{
    "a": "val",
    "b2": "val2",
    "Type": "abc",
    "atrrlist": [{
        "name": "vbv",
        "val": "vbv"
    }],
    "child": [{
        "a": "val",
        "b2": "val2",
        "Type": "abc",
       "atrrlist": [{
            "name": "vbv",
            "val": "vbv"
        }],
        "child": [{
            "a": "val",
            "b2": "val2",
            "Type": "xyz",
            "atrrlist": [{
                "name": "vbv",
                "val": "vbv"
            }]

        }]

    }]
}]

 }
```

Comment: `The code run asynchronously` Where? Everything looks synchronous to me?

Comment: "for loop is asynchronous in nature" no. Where have you read this?

Comment: I agree to CertainPerformance, there is nothing asynchronous here.

Comment: One problem is that your `attrlist` property in the `input` is surrounded by `**` asterisks, for some reason: `"**atrrlist**": [{` resulting in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Edited post.. it was a in attempt to make attrList "Bold" while formatting.

Comment: What is the desired output structure for the given example?

Comment: Your input is not valid: it has loose quotes near `attrlist`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to recurse on *all* object values and not only the ones in the `child` property value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the output structure that you expect, except that it is an array.

I would advise not to pass `output` as an argument, but to make it the *return* value of the `recursion` function. 
The main issue in your code is that you do not concatenate the recursive result to the "current" result. The only time you define `output` it is not an array while you write *"how should I return the final output array?"*. So define it as an array and push the results unto it, also the recursive ones.

```js
function recursion(input) {
    const output = [];
    if (input.Type === "abc") {
        const attrlist = {};
        for (const {name, val} of input.atrrlist) {
            attrlist[name] = val;
        }
        if (input.atrrlist.length > 0) {
            output.push({ [input.a]: attrlist });
        }
    }
    for (const obj of Object.values(input)) {
        if (Object(obj) === obj) {
            output.push(...recursion(obj));
        }
    }
    return output;
}

// Sample input:
const input = {"a": "val","b": "val2","Type": "abc","atrrlist": [{"name": "category","val": "furniture"}],"child": [{"a": "val","b2": "val2","Type": "abc","atrrlist": [{"name": "product","val": "chair"}],"child": [{"a": "val","b2": "val2","Type": "abc","atrrlist": [{"name": "color","val": "blue"}],"child": [{"a": "val","b2": "val2","Type": "xyz","atrrlist": [{"name": "vbv","val": "vbv"}]}]}]}]};

console.log(recursion(input));
```